# what is causing my footer not to sit at the bottom?

Tags: css, wordpress

http://twoandahalfmiles.polymath.io

When I login to wordpress and I have the admin bar at the top, the footer (the wooded area) sits perfectly at the bottom of the website. When I view the website when I am not logged in I then see the footer end and the body content (background) come back in (with a tiny little smiley face on the bottom left).

http://twoandahalfmiles.polymath.io

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well the smileyface is definitely pushing the footer up. Just remove it!

Comment: wow.. who knew that would be so easy. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: I'd say the image was set to 'display:block' so standard css behavior would make it appear on its own line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smiley face is displaying on its own line. Simply remove the smiley face and the footer will stay at the bottom.